# How to make an web page translator which can display both original text and translated text at once?

Tags: reactjs, translation

I'm making an web service espcially using react and next.js with vercel and planetsclae.

My goal is making an web version of this kind of service.
which can navigate through urls and get page translated with its original text displayed together.
[image]

At first , I had no idea how to do this so I just scraped the webpage texts, and get it translated by google translation api and then displayed in line by line like this(picture under)

[image]

But I found out that it costs too much if there's too many users and server delay is too long so that I have to pay for pro version of some services(cause I'm on serverless environment).
Thus, I started to wonder is this a right way.

Could you give me some advices how to make this kind of service?
I want to know the operation logic of the application of first picture, and make it on web version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use-case for Static Site Generation (SSG). And [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) (based on React) is just the framework for you! NextJS will render static html pages of any language you like if you use a translating service like Google Translate. You could also use ChatGPT, which has a free-tier API currently.

Basically, what you do is create a dynamic route for each language you want to include. Example:

`/pages/about-us/[lang].js`

And in that file, you'd do something like this:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const locale = params.locale;
  // code to fetch document
  // code to convert document to 'locale'
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const langs = await getAllPossibleLangs();

  const paths = langs.map((locale) => ({
    params: { locale },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
}
```

this will create an html page for each laguage you provide, for example: `/about-us/en_US.html`, `/about-us/zh_CN.html`

These pages are generated at build time, so you only pay for when content is changed. You can also do Incremental SSG, as well, which automatically rebuilds pages when changes are detected on the data source.

Comment: Also, check out [this article](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) about internationalized routing in NextJS.

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to translate a random multiple pages by given url and see the translated text and it's original text together I mean in the same page, so I don't think SSG is the option.